# Error while compiling telegram source code

Tags: android, android-ndk, telegram

I'm trying to compile telegram android source on my machine. I'm getting following error which i'm not understanding.

`Error:error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct user_fxsr_struct user_fpxregs_struct'`

Strangly, When I just build, it successfully builds but when I try to run on the emulator on AS, it throws above error.

Answer (score 0):

you should use older version of NDK such as r11c.
you can download it from
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

after downloading, to set the NDK address go to project structure -> SDK location -> android NDK location